# Why is grep not finding integer*2?

Tags: linux, grep

For example

```
grep -n 'integer*2' *.f
```

Shows nothing.But

```
grep -n '*2' *.f


main.f:57:      integer*2 itime(nxmax)
main.f:605:             dxy=((xsource(is)-xobs)**2+(ysource(is)-yobs)**2)**.5
main.f:622:           chisum=chisum+diff2/uobs**2
model.f:15:      integer*2 veli(nxmax)
model.f:52:      size2=size**2
time.f:151:      integer*2 itime(nxmax)
```

I really do not understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*` is an operator, meaning "match the previous term 0 or more times".  So `integer*2` matches

```
intege2
integer2
integerr2
integerrr2
     :
```

none of which appear in your program.  `*` at the *beginning* of an RE is meaningless (there's no previous term), so is either ignored or treated as match for a `*`.  Escape the `*` to have it match an actual star:

```
'integer\*2'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your grep is using a regex. (Star is being interpreted differently than you might believe). Try

```
grep -F -n 'integer*2' *.f
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `grep` is interpreting the search argument as a regular expression, in which `*` is meant as "zero or more of the preceding".  So `'integer*2` would match `intege2` as well as `integerrrrr2` since `*` applies to the preceding `r` but will not match the literal `integer*2`.

Escape it with a backslash to interpret it as a literal `*` and you should get the desired matches:

```
grep -n 'integer\*2' *.f
```